# How to shuffle a pandas dataframe according to a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe that can be grouped by a `person` column (A, B, C, D, etc.), and each of those people has certain number of records. The question is how can I shuffle those people without changing the order within each group?

Comment: Are the records from the same person together already or they are scattered around, which if is true, how would you want to shuffle that?

Comment: Sorry. I should have made it less confusing in that regard. They are already put together I would say.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Person=list('BBBEEEAAACCCZZZZZ'),
    Other=range(17)
))

    Other Person
0       0      B
1       1      B
2       2      B
3       3      E
4       4      E
5       5      E
6       6      A
7       7      A
8       8      A
9       9      C
10     10      C
11     11      C
12     12      Z
13     13      Z
14     14      Z
15     15      Z
16     16      Z
```

---

Use `np.random.permutation` to reshuffle `Person` and then `set_index`/`loc`/`reset_index`

```
df.set_index('Person').loc[
    np.random.permutation(df.Person.unique())
].reset_index()

   Person  Other
0       Z     12
1       Z     13
2       Z     14
3       Z     15
4       Z     16
5       A      6
6       A      7
7       A      8
8       C      9
9       C     10
10      C     11
11      B      0
12      B      1
13      B      2
14      E      3
15      E      4
16      E      5
```